# Capture and edit part of string using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to check several strings...the format of each string could be the following:

```
I-IVWM_Ask-21_(max_2h)
```

or

```
D-7849_DG303_(max_4h)
```

or

```
Aliante_Privato
```

I need to capture text in brackets, first part of string outside brackets and replace underscore with spaces.

I'm tring to use preg_match in PHP, as follow

```
preg_replace('/\([^)]*\)|[()]/', '', $string);
```

The code above remove string and brackets but leave underscore and doesn't capture the string inside brackets.

Any help to figure out my issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might do is first match the pattern, and for the match replace the parenthesis and underscores with a space using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Pattern to match the strings:

```
^[^\s()]+(?:\([^()]*\))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s()]+` Match 1+ chars other than parenthesis or whitespace chars
- `(?:\([^()]*\))?` Optionally match the part between parenthesis
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tBMNKv/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/gn3vh)

For example

```
$strings = [
    "I-IVWM_Ask-21_(max_2h)",
    "D-7849_DG303_(max_4h)",
    "Aliante_Privato"
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    $pattern = "/^[^\s()]+(?:\([^()]*\))?$/";
    echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($x) {
        return trim(preg_replace("/[()_]+/", " ", $x[0]));
    }, $str) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
I-IVWM Ask-21 max 2h
D-7849 DG303 max 4h
Aliante Privato
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm trying to understand the pattern but it's very criptic to me....is there a way to get back the string splitted in three groups? The first should be the code with a letter, minus sign and four numbers/letters ( D-7849 or I-IVWM, the second shold be the model name ( Ask-21 .. for example ), the last group should be the duration ( max 2h ) Thanks a lot again...still needs to learn a lot about regex...

Comment: @Federico Like this? `^([A-Z]-[A-Z0-9]{4})_([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)_\(([^()]+)\)` https://regex101.com/r/AkPfD6/1 Then you can replace the underscore from the 3rd group using preg_replace_callback as in the example.

Comment: Unbelieveble!...the power of regex is incredible. Thanks a lot again for invaluable help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$strings = [
    "I-IVWM_Ask-21_(max_2h)",
    "D-7849_DG303_(max_4h)",
    "Aliante_Privato"
];

$result = array_map('trim', preg_filter('~[_()]+~', ' ', $strings));
```

Comment: Really interesting Casimir…can I ask what’s the purpose of the square bracket? Needs to understand array_map function too

Comment: @Federico: square brackets are not different than something like `[A-Z]`, they defines a character class, except that this one doesn't contain a range of letters but only 3 characters `(`, `)`, `_`. `array_map` applies a function to each item of an array and returns a new array. The applied function is simply `trim`. Note that this answer has nothing special and the code doesn't check the format, but I wrote it only to show a certain conciseness to treat an array "in one shot". Following the same idea, you can use `preg_grep` to select items that match the desired format.

Comment: Great feedback and support...as usual. Thanks a lot